# Draw Paths Automatically

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, features, fme-form, feature-extraction

[image]

I have the following data:

The pink represents digitized hiking trails done on a different software that is completely inaccurate compared to raster images. They do however have attributes with the hiking trail names.
The rest of the features represent true and accurate street and walking path features. I need to somehow make it so that the features similar to the pink ones are extracted and have the attributes of the digitzed hiking trails.

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and have no Spatial Analyst and Network Analysis.

FME solutions are also welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no silver bullet for this kind of task and there is a risk that some of the work you would need to do manually, particularly verifying the correct lines's attributes were transferred as required.

I would try multiple things and see how it goes:

1. Make a backup of your datasets.
2. Make sure you have custom unique ID field for each line segment in the pink and blue lines. You might need to transfer the attributes from the pink layer later on to the source.
3. Use [Integrate](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000) GP tool to make your features align first (supported in all licenses). Play with the tolerance and find something that is close enough.
4. Test using the [Spatial Adjustment toolbar](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m800000030000000) and try [transferring attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m80000001v000000) between the integrated lines. Spatial adjustment tools provide quite robust semi-automatic ways to transfer attributes quickly between features, so it might do the trick for you.

Comment: I'm giving it a go!

From the first try, I would emphasize backing up datasets, since the Integrate tool doesn't produce an output like the other tools.

Comment: I would recommend Alex's recipe, except as step 4, I would calculate a small buffer of the pink lines (like 1 metre, just to make a polygon ouz of it) and then spatially join the attributes of these buffers to a hiking path segment, if it is completely contained (WITHIN). This prevents features at crossings to get joined onto either. This might not be the most effective way, but it has been the most automatised and accurate one for me a couple of times now for similar examples

Comment: Thanks!

I've tried a combination of both and there's not a completely automatic way of solving this problem because the data is so inaccurate!

Comment: @JayKay_90, I've suspected this. But do use the attribute transfer tool where you could click on the source feature and then on the target feature and the attributes will be moved - this is a huge time saver!

Answer (score 2):

For an FME solution, you might want to try searching for near-parallel lines and then merging attributes (FeatureMerger) if they are suitably "parallel".

There are a few potential ways to do detect parallelism in FME listed here (none require perfectly parallel):
https://safecommunity.force.com/CommunityAnswers?id=906a0000000d7pBAAQ

The upside of an FME method is that it can be automated; the downside is that the quality of the results will vary depending on how you set up the FME workspace. Maybe use it for a first pass and then check/fix and remaining ones with ArcGIS per Alex's answer.